# How to capture all network traffic in a Chrome Tab using fiddler

Tags: google-chrome, fiddler

I want to use fiddler to capture all network traffic in a Chrome Tab.
So I 
* start fiddler in my machine
* click 'Any Process' and the cursor change to '+'
* drag the cursor to a chrome tab. 
* see 'Any Process' change to 'chrome:26260'

But the problem is when I go different site in the chrome tab, I don't see any network traffic capture in fiddler.

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: PID is changed when you type a URL in Chrome.

You can check this by using Chrome's own process manager(<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>) and watch process ID. It remains the same when you navigating with mouse click, however when typing a URL in address bar, Chrome closes the current process and creates a new one thus a new PID -- even it's still the same tab -- and your filter will fail.

I don't know anyway to change this behavior, you need to re-target the tab, or capture all traffic, or maybe just using Chrome's own <kbd>F12</kbd>